# How can I find p-value of 100 samples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have used this code to find the t-value how can I find p-value of 100 samples.

```
sample_mean = 12.75
sample_std = 2
sample_size = 100
pop_mean = 13.04

t_statistic = (sample_mean - pop_mean) / (sample_std / np.sqrt(sample_size))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test

Comment: samples as random variates?